# Spring boot Embedded Tomcat does not establish multiple connections from the same src IP

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp, connection, embedded-tomcat

I have spring boot application 2.5.8 that uses embedded Tomcat. This server listens to port 8081.

When a client establishes TCP connection with my server, it works ok.

But when client is trying simultaniously to setablish 2 connections from different ports - one connection is established. But the second connection is not established.
In wireshark I see the next:

[image]

Connection from port 56542 is established, but connection from port 64005 is never established.

What could be a reason? How to solve this issue?

Comment: check server.tomcat.threads.max if set in application.properties, default value is 200. so default should be fine. alternatively enable the debug and check the log file.

Comment: @kus, server.tomcat.threads.max is not configured, so it's default 200. What could be another reason?

Comment: As suggested capture the log and share it. for reference i just tested, I can see two thread in log file and both request was successful.   you can also check how both request are triggered there might be something wrong.

Comment: @kus, I found an issue. I've recoreded pcaps from both sides (from server side and from client side) and found that there is some network issue and packets are lost. Client is trying to establish connection -> send packet -> packet is lost -> server doesn't recieve this packet -> no connection.